# Swift Watchkit let user move cell (row) in a table when running app

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, watchkit

I have a table list that is order by create date using a Realm database. I am trying to find a way to let the user when using the app, drag a row (cell) to a new position in the table.

I was hoping something like this for Deletes could be used:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:    UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no editing mode (like the one in `UITableView`) in `WKInterfaceTable`. Also, because there are no drag gestures exposed in WatchKit, there is no way to duplicate this functionality in the current version.

One approach might be to add your own control that toggles an edit mode, then expose buttons in each cell that move the row up or down. This would require a bit of work, and actually, I'm not sure it would be a good user experience due to the limited screen real estate.

Comment: I was thinking about putting and up and down arrow on the row when it is selected. Thanks for your help.